# How save update applied on your page html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

in my page html I have a div with size A4 as page
and in this div I add some elements using drag and drop

So I need to save this div in the same state after drag and drop elements after reresh page
or after lanch the app again

should I use database (in server side ) or local storage

https://kdiouri.proposify.biz/proposals this is a link of an application that do the some things

Answer (score 2):

If you want to persist information you can use LocalStorage:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being *barely more than a link to an external site* is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)